# Angular bootstrap-select continue showing options after select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select, angular-bootstrap

I noticed that there is an issue in [angular bootstrap select](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select)(The demo section)
when you select an option, this one continue showing the options instead of being hidden. 
And if the **ng-model** attribute is not used this work fine.

This is the **[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/swZfjkC0pCWmoqs56j0E?p=preview)**.

A section of code:

```
      <select toggle selectpicker ng-model="form">
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
      </select>
```

Regards,

Comment: Can you add a [fiddle](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2F&ei=Y8_WU-yvCo2UyATKlIC4CQ&usg=AFQjCNGAWwtYY97WCaSMXHxOHxSDDwT6Vw&sig2=5rMdelMrTq-KLxTPXqawQg&bvm=bv.71778758,d.aWw) for this. It is hard to tell exactly what the problem is if I cannot see all of the code for it.

Comment: I added already a plunker(EXAMPLE)

Comment: `element.selectpicker('refresh')` is clearing the existing `lis` and adding new ones, so the event you had bound are lost. That is why it works when no ng-model is used, since refresh is not called then

Answer (score 1):

It seems like events bound in the directive `angular-bootstrap-select.extra` on the `li` list items does not get executed when ng-model is attached to this. Reason being:- In the directive `angular-bootstrap-select` when a model value changes it calls `element.selectpicker('refresh');` which eventually in the refresh methods removes and recreates the list items, so the click events bound in the directive `angular-bootstrap-select.extra` on the li's are lost. You can probably place a quick fix by using event delegation on the parent.

Try:

```
 element.next().on('click', 'li', function () {
       target.toggleClass('open')
});
```

Instead of :-

```
 element.next().find('li').bind('click', function () {
    target.toggleClass('open')
 })
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fdlwYCTcrZVlVtVMlMLL?p=preview)**

Comment: Good job! The other thing is when you click to the select and you choose another select without choose an option in the first one, both will display options, how can I fix that?

Comment: @Mils Sorry i did not get your question?

Comment: actually you answered to my question, jut I noticed another issue
Thank you.

Comment: @Mils Yeah i got that.. :) But i did not understand the issue.. :)

Comment: the issue is at a given time you can notice two select show the dropdown list, normally when you choose another select the other one should hide his options. Something like that: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/199141issue.png

Comment: @Mils ah got it... Yeah i guess it is because the component doesn't handle click outside to hide it...